# BindingExpression Path error in View Model Commands

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, command

I'm having trouble with the commands in my viewmodel bound to my user control in my WPF application. The commands are run when the user checks or unchecks a `checkBox`. That being said, the commands are obviously bound to `checkBoxes`.

After running the program my output window has the following error for each command (note that the commands do not function during run time when the `checkBoxes` are checked or unchecked):

`System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'MyCommand' property not found on 'object' 'ViewModel' (HashCode=3383440)'.  BindingExpression:Path=MyCommand; DataItem='ViewModel' (HashCode=3383440); target element is 'CheckBox' (Name='checkBox1'); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')`

This is what my XAML looks like:

```xml
<CheckBox Content="CheckBox" Command="{Binding MyCommand}" .../>
```

C# code in my View Model:

```cs
private Command _myCommand;

public Command MyCommand { get { return _myCommand; } }
private void MyCommand_C()
{
    //This is an example of how my commands interact with my model
    _dataModel._groupBoxEnabled = true;
}
```

Inside constructor:

```cs
_myCommand = new Command(MyCommand_C);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign the view model to the View's DataContext. What code do you have in your *.xaml.cs? Should be something like:

```
public MyView( )
{
    this.DataContext = new ViewModel( );
}
```

In the future, you can tell your view model is not hooked up by the info in the output:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error:
>   'MyCommand' property not found on '**object**' 'ViewModel'
>   (HashCode=3383440)'. BindingExpression:Path=MyCommand;
>   DataItem='ViewModel' (HashCode=3383440); target element is 'CheckBox'
>   (Name='checkBox1'); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')

The **object** it's talking about is the DataContext which, if it is showing as of type 'object', it is not of type 'ViewModel' meaning you haven't assigned it to the DataContext yet.

To answer the question in the comments about interacting with the data:

Commands allow you to further separate the logic from the UI, which is great. But at some point you may want to talk back to the UI from the ViewModel. To do this you need to use properties that can [notify the UI of when they are changed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx). So in your command you can set this a property on the ViewModel (say IsChecked) that the CheckBox's Checked property is bound to. So your Xaml looks like:

```
<CheckBox Content="CheckBox" Checked="{Binding IsChecked}" Command="{Binding MyCommand}" .../>
```

And your ViewModel may look like:

```
private Command _myCommand;
private bool _isChecked;

public Command MyCommand { get { return _myCommand; } }
public bool IsChecked
{
    /* look at the article to see how to use getters and setters */
}

private void MyCommand_C()
{
    IsChecked = !IsChecked;
    _dataModel._groupBoxEnabled = IsChecked;
}
```

if you want to wrap a property on an object that is already a property for the view model, simply use (what I refer to as) wrapper properties.

```
public bool IsChecked
{
    get
    {
        return _dataModel.MyCheckBox;
    }
    set
    {
        if(_dataModel != null)
        {
            _dataModel.MyCheckBox = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
        }
        // Exception handling if _dataModel is null
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I also have a data model. The commands interact with the data in my data model, so it still shows a BindingExpression path error. What do I need to include to interact with that model correctly?

Comment: What do you mean? Maybe you could explain a little more in the question and/or post more code, as it would be helpful.

Comment: I've added some contents to the command method. As you can see, I call to properties in the data model.

Comment: What if my `CheckBox` control has it's `IsChecked` property set to `{Binding DataModel.MyCheckBox}`?

Comment: Gotta run for now. If this helped, don't forget to mark as answer and upvote! Good luck!